# Displaying the complete file directory on AWS Linux web server using BASH

Tags: amazon-linux

How can I display the complete file directory of my EC2 server in AWS using BASH?

I've tried searching through with $tree, but I think I've got my wires crossed.

Comment: `ls -aR`? It would be useful to rephrase that question.

Comment: I've now edited it, I'm trying to display the entire file directory, but ls -aR gives me;
.:
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .ssh

./.ssh:
.  ..  authorized_keys
And I have Java8, tomcat installed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with AWS. It's just a Linux VM.

Comment: The server is indeed a VM - Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09 (HVM), but I was under the impression some commands were different depending....

Comment: considering the answer, shouldn't you guys redact the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have root on an AWS server, so sudo

```
$ sudo ls -aR /
```